# Visual Studios Ignoring File

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, directsound

Visual Studios is ignoring the file that I am trying to play. With this code it returns false since it doesn't load the file.

```
    result = LoadWaveFile("../Engine/data/sound01.wav", &m_secondaryBuffer1);
if (!result)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the pathname of the file you are trying to load is truly relative to the current working directory of the application.

Comment: Using relative paths is not ever not a mistake. Make it an absolute path.

Comment: 'current working directory' is rapidly getting to be an annoyance in anything but trivial console apps.

Comment: @IInspectable : What?  If I decoded your double-negative correctly, you're suggesting applications should always bake-in hard paths.  That's usually a much, much worse idea. If anything, you want a relative path that's relative to your executable's location.

Comment: @JoeZ There's a difference between an absolute path and a hardcoded path. I was advising to use the former, not the latter.

Comment: @IInspectable : Ok.  When I read "make it an absolute path", I was envisioning `LoadWaveFile("C:\\Users\\Me\\My Projects\\This Project\\Engine\\Data\\sound01.wav", ...)` or the like.  What you're saying is that you need to _construct_ an absolute path, but that absolute path is still relative to something determined at run time.

Comment: @JoeZ - many users have no idea where their app executable is, but can easily navigate to jpegs, avi's etc. from 'Computer'.  Relative paths from 'Program Files', or 'Program Files (x86)' are just an annoyance that can easily break.

Comment: @JoeZ I didn't realize that you would equate absolute path with a hardcoded absolute path, even though someone who doesn't know, which tool to use, or even that a tool exists that returns the path to the executable that started this process, to *construct* the absolute path. Thank you for bringing that to my attention. Dialecticus' answer provides both the instructions and the tool to use.

Comment: @IInspectable : I think the missing word was "construct".  Where I work (which is with EEs more than CS folks), "make it an absolute path" usually translates to baked in hard paths.  I've been burned too many times by hard-coded absolute paths so maybe I have PTSD.  In Perl, I live by `FindBin`, which is the Perl equivalent of `GetModuleFileName` below, roughly.

Comment: @MartinJames : I understand that.  But, most users aren't writing software; rather, they're just subjected to software others wrote.  I guess it's up to us to help them climb that learning curve.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use relative path on current working directory. Construct instead an absolute path, combining [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) and your original relative path. Current working directory is unreliable, and should not be used.

EDIT: What's wrong with current directories? In short it's volatile. First, the process may not start in the expected directory (like it was in your case). The user may create a shortcut to the app and specify any starting directory there. Second, there are functions in Windows API (notably `GetOpenFileName`) that can change the current directory as a side effect. Third, some third part library that the app uses can change current directory. Fourth, current directory is unique in the process, shared among threads, so even if you call `SetCurrentDirectory` before relying on it, some other thread can change it in the mean time.

In small demo app case, all those causes are almost non-existing, and you can even prevent the first cause by setting Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Working Directory to $(OutDir), if you are ever going to start the app from debugger. That's a very specific use case, though, so I would go with the more robust solution that does not rely on volatile nature of current directory.